# How can I fix CSRF Request Validation Token error

Tags: csrf-token

I fixed CSRF VULNERABILITY by adding [**validateAntiforgeyToken] **attribute in controller method also added a @**Html.AntiForgeryToken** in cshtml but still I am getting __RequestValidation is not present exception. How can I fix it?